# Making an ASP.NET application viewable on mobile browsers

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an old ASP.NET web application (Web Forms, no MVC) and I would like to make it "look nice" in mobile browsers, while keeping the current design for desktop browsers.

One of my options is CSS media queries , but then - is there a list of standard screen sizes I should adapt it for?

I also read about Modernizr - but it seems to just detect browser capabilities, and I wouldn't know how to use it for my purposes.

What would be my best bet? Appreciate it.

Comment: There is no easy way, either you have design it to auto change size, either you detect the device and use two different pages, one for mobile and one for desktop. Needs work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recurred to CSS media queries. Here's a nice introduction. Much appreciated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 1):

You should take a close look at jquery-mobile which has a lot of built in functions to deal with both changing the display based on device as well as a variety of layouts pre-optimized for mobile views.

Take a look at this link for way more information : http://jquerymobile.com/

However this would not necessarily be easy, depending on the complexity and overall layout of the "normal" web page. However it could easily be implemented to judge what device is being used and then switch to an already defined layout.